# Jquery Integrating two different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello Guyz here is my code

```
 $("[tagname='b']").click(function(){
    $('.dp_right_panel').hide();
    $('.dp_right_show').show();
    var a;
    $('.font_image').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('title').substr(0, 1)=='B'){

        a += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
    }

    });
      $('.fonts_div_show').html(a);

  });
```

above code works fine ... but as you can see in my code iam passing `a` then it will be compared with `A` and will get the `html` code... i want to do till `z` that is from a-z , so i can not keep writing this code...
here is my other code

```
  $('.dp_top_panel_alphabet_ul li').click(function(){

  console.log($(this).attr('title'));

  });
```

which will output `A` when `A` is clicked and `B` when `B` is clicked... now to integrate with this code with my previous code so that when `$(this).attr('title')` should be directly passed to my previous code...

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: $("a") are `<a...>` tags

Comment: sorry its <a > tag its letter a.. k let me put other variable..EDITED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use regular expression.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('[A-Za-z]');
$('.font_image').each(function(){
if($(this).attr('title').substr(0, 1).match(pattern)){

    a += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
}

});
$('.fonts_div_show').html(a);
```